# Trying to hook up Dual Monitor Samsung S32D850T but can't get 2560 x 1440 using a ASUS GFX 970

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution, hdmi, dvi

I have 2  Samsung S32D850T 32" monitors (S32D850T) that work great through DVI however the top resolution I can get from them is 1920x1080.  Of course the drivers of the graphics card (ASUS GFX 970) says it can go up to 2560 x 1440.  When I go up to that resolution the text gets all funky as though clear type text wasn't on.  Clearly I'm missing something and need to either get another graphics card or use a better cord etc.  My ASUS GFX 970 as 2 DVI ports, 1 display port and 1 HDMI port on it.  My monitors support both HDMI and DVI.  Are either of these solutions possible?

1) Use the DisplayPort and use a splitter to go dual with either DVI or HDMI and get the top resolution for both (2560 x 1440)

2) Use the DisplayPort for 1 monitor and use the HDMI port for the other monitor and get the top resolution for both (2560 x 1440)

Again right now the highest I get is 1920 x 1080.

Here are the full specs of my machine

> ```
> Operating System
>       Windows 8.1 64-bit
>   CPU
>       Intel Core i3/i5/i7 6xxx @ 3.50GHz  27 °C
>       Skylake 14nm Technology
>   RAM
>       16.0GB
>   Motherboard
>       ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. MAXIMUS VIII HERO (LGA1151)   29 °C
>   Graphics
>       S32D850 (1920x1080@60Hz)
>       S32D850 (1920x1080@60Hz)
>       4095MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970 (ASUStek Computer Inc)    45 °C
>   Storage
>       465GB Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB (SSD)   35 °C
>       931GB Western Digital WDC WD10EZEX-00BN5A0 (SATA)   39 °C
>       465GB Hitachi HDS72505 0KLAT80 USB Device (SSD) 35 °C
>   Optical Drives
>       TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-S203N SCSI CdRom Device
>   Audio
>       Realtek High Definition Audio
> ```

Comment: Have you tried using just one monitor? Use a combo of ports and don't use splitters. I'm currently using DVI-D and DisplayPort.

Comment: When I go to a single monitor using a DVI connection I still get the same results which is that the resolution can't go above 1920 x 1080 without looking funky.

Comment: Is this the DVI cable that came with monitor? Cause it needs DVI-D cable to display 1440p.

Comment: Looking at the cable it looks like a DVI-D (Single Link) connector.  I referenced the difference in cable connectors from this site. http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/pc-peripheral/how-tell-dvi-i-dvi-d-cables-apart-3365585/

Comment: This is an image of what my connectors look like on my ASUS 970 OC.
http://images.bit-tech.net/content_images/2014/09/nvidia-geforce-gtx-970-review/asus970-2b.jpg

Comment: Top DVI connection is DVI-I. The bottom is DVI-D. Have you got a DisplayPort cable?

Comment: I don't think I do.  I may have to go purchase that one.

Comment: Did you plug the DVI-D cable into the bottom connection in that picture? Maybe cause you're using both DVIs, it's limiting the resolution to DVI-I (max 1080p)

Comment: Just tried it.  Both act the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to use the DisplayPort for one monitor and a high end HDMI cable for the other.  I could have used a DVI cable but it would have to be a Dual Link DVI cable.  The ones I had were both single link and didn't have the bandwidth for the resolution.

Comment: You didn't receive a DVI-D cable from Samsung? You didn't say you were using DIV-I cables and I would have said that's you're issue :/ That's pretty cheap of them.